# Master page post back on click of sub-menu item

Tags: c#

I have a master page where in I have menu list items are :- Add Staff, Add Venue,Add Time Sheet , Setting , Invoicing. Sub Menu Items of Settings are :- General Settings , Users , Roles , Sub-Contractors. my concern is When I click on General Setting , Users  my entire page gets post back. I do not want this to happen. Instead I want only the content that needs to be refreshed/change.and my second concern is :- all Sub-Menu items of settings shown on all setting page as i go from General Setting to Users how is it happen.

Any quick / easy solution to the above issue?

Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is this? WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net WebForms, ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Use  ASP.NET tags to use Ajax to change the tabs asynchronously.
2. (Better) Use a javascript framework like JQuery or Dojo to create the effect in javascript. (Note that Microsoft is including JQuery in newer web templates)